# Criação de um Splash

Tags: java, android

Estou criando um splash mas esse splach esta a parar o meu App, ele funciona por alguns segundos depois fecha automaticamente o meu App para de funcionar e não abre mais.

```
public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 3000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if(actionBar != null){
            actionBar.hide();
        }

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                Intent startActivityIntent = new Intent(Splash.this, AuthUIActivity.class);
                startActivity(startActivityIntent);
                Splash.this.finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
    }
}
```

Comment: Coloque o log de quando o aplicativo fecha.

Comment: poderia ser mais especifico porque não entendi la muito bem

Comment: Quando você está rodando o aplicativo, no Android Studio mostra o log do que está acontecendo na aba 'Run', quando o aplicativo para de funcionar aparece o erro nesse log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Não é muito bom utilizar *Splash Screens***, pois assim você retarda o tempo necessário para abrir o app, e os usuários não gostam de apps lentos.

No entanto, caso você precise fazer algum processamento (verificar credenciais, procurar atualizações, inicializar banco de dados) antes que a tela principal do seu app seja exibida, então exibir uma splash não é uma má ideia, desde que ela dure exatamente o tempo necessário para realizar as inicializações necessárias.

Exemplo de implementação:

**Crie um XML (*e.g.* `splash_background.xml`) na pasta `res/drawable`**

```
<?xml version=”1.0" encoding=”utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android=”http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

     <item android:drawable=”@color/colorPrimary” />

     <item>
         <bitmap
             android:gravity=”center”
             android:src=”@mipmap/ic_launcher” />
     </item>
</layer-list>
```

**Crie um tema para a tela de Splash no arquivo `styles.xml`**

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_background</item>
</style>
```

**No `Manifest`, configure sua SplashActivity como a tela principal e defina o tema dela como `SplashTheme`**

```
<activity
    android:name=".SplashActivity"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

**Agora, no código da sua SplashActivity, basta fazer as inicializações necessárias, e ao final delas, chamar a outra Activity (*e.g.* `HomeActivity`)**

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Obs.: Não é necessário chamar setContentView() pois o tema
        //SplashTheme dessa Activity já define uma imagem de fundo.

        // Códigos de inicialização do app

        startActivity(new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

Fontes: [Right Way to create Splash Screen on Android](https://android.jlelse.eu/right-way-to-create-splash-screen-on-android-e7f1709ba154)